# Calling a synchronous method in an async fashion?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, ldap-query

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC WebApi project and one of the methods needs to make a LDAP search. The amount of information the search retrieves from the LDAP server ensures the call takes at least 7 seconds to complete. The call, as it uses the `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` classes and methods, is synchronous and unmodifiable.

The amount of traffic this API will receive is rather big (even though the API is in an internal network) so 7 seconds for each call to the LDAP server is not a good idea. So I want to know this:

- Is it a good idea to wrap this in an asynchronous method?
- What's the proper way to async this call? (is `await Task.Run(() => Search(params))` an acceptable way?)

Comment: Task.Run is not a great idea in ASP.Net MVC. Each request is it's own thread so you are not going to gain anything anyway.

Comment: If the search takes 7s, perhaps you should sync the complete data you need to your own database once a day or so instead. And than query that.

Comment: Making the call async will not speed up the response time for the client, it would just (possibly) reduce the amount of blocked threads on the server. So if the 7 seconds are problematic, you need to change the process overall, maybe with partial LDAP results or similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in the comment I don't see how making the call asynchronous would help at all. Running it in another thread and awaiting (as per your "what is the proper way..." question) does use as many resources as synchronously calling and waiting.

Note, however, that the `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` classes such as `LdapCollection` do have async support with the older APM (Asynchronous Programming Model) style (e.g. [`BeginSendRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.protocols.ldapconnection.beginsendrequest?view=netframework-4.7.2)/[`EndSendRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.protocols.ldapconnection.endsendrequest?view=netframework-4.7.2)).

You can easily wrap APM-style APIs to awaitable Task-based style by using [`TaskFactory<TResult>.FromAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory-1.fromasync), this would be the "proper way" of using these classes with async. See also [Interop with Other Asynchronous Patterns and Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types#tasks-and-the-asynchronous-programming-model-apm).

Comment: Used your advice to reimplement the method in an async fashion and it worked flawlessly. Of course, as you said, there was no real gain in speed, but that was solved when I was told that I could discard most of the requested data (adjusting the query to retrieve only what was needed reduced the execution time to bit under 3 seconds and subsequent queries seem to be cached).

Comment: @Léster Thank you for the feedback, glad to know my reply helped somewhat. :)

Answer (score 2):

PD: Based on Lucero's answer, here's an extension method that hides the APM calls and exposes itself as a regular `Task<T>` async method:

```
public static async Task<DirectoryResponse> SendRequestAsync(this LdapConnection conn, string target, string filter,
    SearchScope searchScope, params string[] attributeList)
{
    if (conn == null)
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException();
    }
    var search_request = new SearchRequest(target, filter, searchScope, attributeList);
    var response = await Task<DirectoryResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(
        conn.BeginSendRequest,
        (iar) => conn.EndSendRequest(iar),
        search_request,
        PartialResultProcessing.NoPartialResultSupport,
        null);
    return response;
}
```

This can also be used as a starting point for your own needs (you can use a similar method to "make" APM-supporting objects behave in Task-based style).